# What's the fastest way to get the points I want out of a huge blob?

Tags: performance, matlab

In MATLAB I have a set of 5393280 points in the form of a decimal-valued vector (x,y,z). How do I represent them in a way that I can quickly collect all the points within some rectangular x-y domain?

Right now I'm representing them as a 3-column matrix, sorted by x-values, and using the following code to extract a rectangular region:

```
mtx_region = mtx_pointList( dxLowerBound < mtx_pointList(:,1) & ...
                            dxUpperBound > mtx_pointList(:,1) & ...
                            dyLowerBound < mtx_pointList(:,2) & ...
                            dyUpperBound > mtx_pointList(:,2), : );
```

However, I suspect that this is slowing my code down considerably.

What is a better way?

Comment: The keyword you are looking for is quadtree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prefiltering all relevant x-values with a binary search could speed up the process.

```
[a,A]=myFind2(mtx_region(:,1),dxLowerBound,dxUpperBound);

xpoints=mtx_region(a:A,:);
mtx_region = xpoints(     dyLowerBound < xpoints(:,2) & ...
                            dyUpperBound > xpoints(:,2), : );
```

Binary search on sorted arrays is already discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20166847/faster-version-of-find-for-sorted-vectors-matlab/20167257#20167257).

```
function [b,c]=myFind2(x,A,B)
a=1;
b=numel(x);
c=1;
d=numel(x);
while (a+1<b||c+1<d)
    lw=(floor((a+b)/2));
    if (x(lw)<A)
        a=lw;
    else
        b=lw;
    end
    lw=(floor((c+d)/2));
    if (x(lw)<=B)
        c=lw;
    else
        d=lw;
    end
end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

if you only need to select once then there is no need to sort at all; filtering can happen in \$ O \left( n \right) \$ while the sort needs \$ O \left( n \log n \right) \$

if you need to select multiple times then put them in a \$ n \times n \$ grid structure, where each grid is a list of points that lie within it

Comment: MathJax was introduced to Code Review [yesterday](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1708/27623)